# State of a class?

Tags: python

Gotta write a class that every instance has the same state

```
class Mockup:
   __slots__=('A','B','C','state')
   def __init__(self,A,B,C):
      self.A=A
      self.B=B
      self.C=C
      self.state='MOCKUP'
```

Is this right?

Comment: if one instance change state, any other instance must change their state

Comment: Do they really need to be different instances then? You could look up one of the various singleton patterns.

Comment: Guess, you are right, i should try with singleton pattern, thank you

Comment: You should probably just use a module then.